# No me recibe variables en el index de una función PHP

Tags: php

Veamos tengo un fichero con funciones(functions.php) y otro dónde encadeno las funciones completando por tanto la lógica del programa (index.php).

Este sería el código de functions.php:

```
//FUNCIÓN QUE TE DEVUELVE TODOS LOS IDPEDIDO E IDARTICULO DE LA TABLA DE MYSQL EN UN ARRAY ASOCIATIVO
function cogeIdPedidoIdArticuloMySQL($conWebService){ 
     //La salida $datosPK_WS es un array asociativo con todos los IDPedido y su idarticulo correspondiente de la tabla de MySQL
     $queryWS= "SELECT IdPedido, idarticulo FROM pedidos";
     $lecturaWS=mysqli_query($conWebService, $queryWS);
 
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($lecturaWS)){
         $datosPK_WS[$row['IdPedido']]=$row['idarticulo']; //Array asociativo
     }

     return $datosPK_WS;
}

//FUNCIÓN QUE TE DEVUELVE TODOS LOS IDPEDIDO E IDARTICULO DE LA TABLA DE MSACCESS EN UN ARRAY ASOCIATIVO
function cogeIdPedidoIdArticuloMSAccess($conMSAccess){
    $queryMS= "SELECT IdPedido, idarticulo FROM pedidos_remoto";
    $lecturaMS=mysqli_query($conMSAccess, $queryMS);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($lecturaMS)){
        $datosPK_MS[$row['IdPedido']]=$row['idarticulo']; //Array asociativo
    }   

    return $datosPK_MS;
}

//FUNCIÓN QUE TE DEVUELVE LOS IDPEDIDOS E IDARTÍCULOS QUE EXISTEN EN MICROSOFT ACCESS PERO NO EN MYSQL
function noExisteEnMySQL($datosPK_WS, $datosPK_MS) {

            //Aquí veo qué registros de la tabla de MS Access no existen en la BD de MySQL
            $DBchangesMS = [];

            // Recorrer arreglo de resultados MSAccess
            foreach($datosPK_MS as $idPedido => $idarticulo) {
            // Si el pedido no existe en resultados de MySQL
                if(!isset($datosPK_WS[$idPedido])) {
                    // Agregar al arreglo
                    $DBchangesMS[] = ['IdPedido' => $idPedido, 'idarticulo' => $idarticulo];
                } 
            }
        
            var_dump($DBchangesMS);
            return $DBchangesMS;
}
```

Y este el código del index.php:

```
 // Preparación de datos para poder realizar todas las operaciones
    cogeIdPedidoIdArticuloMySQL($conWebService);
    cogeIdPedidoIdArticuloMSAccess($conMSAccess);

    echo "<h5>Inserción de los datos de MS Access en la tabla de MySQL</h5>";

    //Veo qué registros (por las PK) están en MSAccess pero no en MySQL
    noExisteEnMySQL($datosPK_WS, $datosPK_MS);
```

Tengo importados en el index.php el fichero de functions.php con un require_once. No comprendo dónde está el fallo, porque me los siguientes errores:

```
Undefined variable: datosPK_WS
Undefined variable: datosPK_MS
```

Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Comment: En el index.html tienes cosas de PHP, es correcto?

Comment: Sí claro, llamadas a funciones como ves, pero se llama index.php, no index.html.

Comment: Bueno, te lo digo por que no es lo que esta puesto...

Comment: Vale, ha sido un fallo mío, lo edito.

Comment: ¿Dónde creas estas dos variables que pasas a esa función: `noExisteEnMySQL($datosPK_WS, $datosPK_MS);`?

Comment: En las dos primeras funciones que he creado. Un ejemplo de creación de una de estas variables es el siguiente: $datosPK_MS[$row['IdPedido']]=$row['idarticulo'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que las variables **son retornadas** desde estas funciones:

```
cogeIdPedidoIdArticuloMySQL($conWebService);
cogeIdPedidoIdArticuloMSAccess($conMSAccess);
```

Pero no estás guardando referencia a ellas. Cuando usas `return` y quieres usar el dato retornado en otro contexto, debes guardar una referencia.

Por ejemplo:

```
 // Preparación de datos para poder realizar todas las operaciones

$datosPK_WS=cogeIdPedidoIdArticuloMySQL($conWebService);
$datosPK_MS=cogeIdPedidoIdArticuloMSAccess($conMSAccess);

echo "<h5>Inserción de los datos de MS Access en la tabla de MySQL</h5>";

//Veo qué registros (por las PK) están en MSAccess pero no en MySQL
noExisteEnMySQL($datosPK_WS, $datosPK_MS);
```

Comment: Básicamente, que de aquellas variables que hago el return, tengo en el index.php que hacerles un = de aquella función que la retorna no? Es decir:

$variableX=funciónQueRetornaVariableX(); ¿Esa sería la estructura no? Gracias.

Comment: Correcto @Sergio. Cuando puedas lee sobre el *ámbito de las variables* en PHP.

Comment: Muchas gracias.